# Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/xxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: paypal, billing

I had created many billing plans and it was working fine till last week. I am trying to delete the plan and i get the error Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/xxxxxxxxxxx. I can provide the plan ID if needed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kannan

Comment: In the error response, are you able to provide the correlation IDs that should be in the JSON response? This will help the support teams. I unfortunately can only reproduce this error with a PayPal redirect step, all direct API calls are going through for me at the current time.

Comment: You should now be good to go on sandbox again

Answer (score 3):

Edit (1:07pm ET): Sandbox issues should now be resolved. Please let me know if there are any issues that persist. Our apologies for the downtime here.

I work over at PayPal on the developer advocacy team. Just to update, beyond the external tickets we have several internal tickets running with reports and verified tests of the sandbox issues, and have escalated the tickets as well. I'll update as I hear more from the teams on potential resolution.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the support. Could you please check the issue arises when i try to update plan, Debug ID is b34671fe256a3.

Comment: Also when trying to fetch plan response code 500, Debug ID 76bf3c86e0f15.

Comment: @user399883 Looks like there was a recurrence of the issue. That should now be resolved again.